# Maximum product prefix string

Tags: algorithm, performance, dynamic-programming, kadanes-algorithm

The following is a demo question from a coding interview site called codility:

> A prefix of a string S is any leading contiguous part of S. For example, "c" and "cod" are prefixes of the string "codility". For simplicity, we require prefixes to be non-empty.
>
> The product of prefix P of string S is the number of occurrences of P multiplied by the length of P. More precisely, if prefix P consists of K characters and P occurs exactly T times in S, then the product equals K * T.
>
> For example, S = "abababa" has the following prefixes:
>
> - "a", whose product equals 1 * 4 = 4,
> - "ab", whose product equals 2 * 3 = 6,
> - "aba", whose product equals 3 * 3 = 9,
> - "abab", whose product equals 4 * 2 = 8,
> - "ababa", whose product equals 5 * 2 = 10,
> - "ababab", whose product equals 6 * 1 = 6,
> - "abababa", whose product equals 7 * 1 = 7.
>
> The longest prefix is identical to the original string. The goal is to choose such a prefix as maximizes the value of the product. In above example the maximal product is 10.

Below is my poor solution in Java requiring O(N^2) time. It is apparently possible to do this in O(N). I was thinking Kadanes algorithm. But I can't think of any way that I can encode some information at each step that lets me find the running max. Can any one think of an O(N) algorithm for this?

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

class Solution {
    public int solution(String S) {
        int N = S.length();
        if(N<1 || N>300000){
            System.out.println("Invalid length");
            return(-1);
        }
        HashMap<String,Integer> prefixes = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            String keystr = "";
            for(int j=i; j>=0; j--) {
                keystr += S.charAt(j);
                if(!prefixes.containsKey(keystr))
                    prefixes.put(keystr,keystr.length());
                else{
                    int newval = prefixes.get(keystr)+keystr.length();
                    if(newval > 1000000000)return 1000000000;
                    prefixes.put(keystr,newval);
                }
            }
        }
        int maax1 = 0;
        for(int val : prefixes.values())
            if(val>maax1)
                maax1 = val;
        return maax1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should not the inner loop (j) iterate in ascending order?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I think that maybe a suffix tree for the inverted string (built on O(n) time) with O(1) queries for suffixes could solve the problem within the required time constraint

Comment: Little Santi - If we just want to find the max product it doesn't matter. The reason I have it like this is that an o(n) solution would probably look backwards too I thought.

Comment: You don't need a hashmap, just an array.  There's a 1:1 mapping between prefixes and integers: the length.  I haven't thought of anything useful to improve the complexity class.  I'm still digging through the confusing and totally-un-commented and un-described way you've coded what I think it just the obvious count matches for every prefix solution.  Generating the prefix as a string N^2 times instead of N times seems odd.  And are you sure this works?  The way you generate the prefix string working backwards means you're sometimes considering e.g. the 2nd and 3rd characters, without the 1st.

Comment: Your solution isn't O(N^2). It has two O(N) nested loops, but inside the inner loop there is an O(N) containsKey (because keystr has O(N) chars, and assuming an O(1) hashmap). So the algorithm is O(N^3) actually.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Codility (the site I got this from) is sure it works. This was a test question so didn't get time for adding comments. You can look at the question statement and ignore the code if that helps.

Comment: @RohitPandey: The problem statement was fine, I just wanted to understand your solution.  You could have added comments, or at least a description, for your SO question.  Can you explain why it's not a problem that `keystr` loops over every possible substring, without excluding substrings that aren't prefixes?  Wouldn't a string like `xabababa` maybe give a wrong result of `ababa`?

Comment: duplicate of this 2-year-old badly titled question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251645/java-programming-task-efficiency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a O(n log n) version based on suffix arrays. There are O(n) construction algorithms for suffix arrays, I just don't have the patience to code them.

Example output (this output isn't O(n), but it's only to show that we can indeed compute all the scores):

```
4*1 a
3*3 aba
2*5 ababa
1*7 abababa
3*2 ab
2*4 abab
1*6 ababab
```

Basically you have to reverse the string, and compute the suffix array (SA) and the longest common prefix (LCP).

Then you have traverse the SA array backwards looking for LCPs that match the entire suffix (prefix in the original string). If there's a match, increment the counter, otherwise reset it to 1. Each suffix (prefix) receive a "score" (SCR) that corresponds to the number of times it appears in the original string.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#define MAX 10050
using namespace std;

int RA[MAX], tempRA[MAX];
int SA[MAX], tempSA[MAX];
int C[MAX];                
int Phi[MAX], PLCP[MAX], LCP[MAX];

int SCR[MAX];

void suffix_sort(int n, int k) {
    memset(C, 0, sizeof C);        

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)        
        C[i + k < n ? RA[i + k] : 0]++;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max(256, n); i++) {                     
        int t = C[i]; 
        C[i] = sum; 
        sum += t;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)        
        tempSA[C[SA[i] + k < n ? RA[SA[i] + k] : 0]++] = SA[i];

    memcpy(SA, tempSA, n*sizeof(int));
}

void suffix_array(string &s) {             
    int n = s.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        RA[i] = s[i] - 1;              

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        SA[i] = i;

    for (int k = 1; k < n; k *= 2) {     
        suffix_sort(n, k);
        suffix_sort(n, 0);

        int r = tempRA[SA[0]] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            int s1 = SA[i], s2 = SA[i-1];
            bool equal = true;
            equal &= RA[s1] == RA[s2];
            equal &= RA[s1+k] == RA[s2+k];

            tempRA[SA[i]] = equal ? r : ++r;     
        }

        memcpy(RA, tempRA, n*sizeof(int));
    } 
}

void lcp(string &s) {
    int n = s.size();

    Phi[SA[0]] = -1;         
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)  
        Phi[SA[i]] = SA[i-1];  

    int L = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (Phi[i] == -1) { 
            PLCP[i] = 0; 
            continue; 
        }
        while (s[i + L] == s[Phi[i] + L]) 
            L++;

        PLCP[i] = L;
        L = max(L-1, 0);                      
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)                 
        LCP[i] = PLCP[SA[i]];
}

void score(string &s) {
    SCR[s.size()-1] = 1;

    int sum = 1;
    for (int i=s.size()-2; i>=0; i--) {
        if (LCP[i+1] < s.size()-SA[i]-1) {
            sum = 1;
        } else {
            sum++; 
        }
        SCR[i] = sum;
    }
}

int main() {
    string s = "abababa";
    s = string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()) +".";

    suffix_array(s);
    lcp(s);
    score(s);

    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++) {
        string ns = s.substr(SA[i], s.size()-SA[i]-1);
        ns = string(ns.rbegin(), ns.rend());
        cout << SCR[i] << "*" << ns.size() << " " << ns << endl;
    }
}
```

Most of this code (specially the suffix array and LCP implementations) I have been using for some years in contests. This version in special I adapted from [this one I wrote some years ago](https://github.com/juanplopes/icpc/blob/master/uva/760.cpp).

Comment: This isn't codegolf.SE.  Lines like `tempSA[C[SA[i] + k < n ? RA[SA[i] + k] : 0]++] = SA[i];` could *really* use comments, or being split into multiple lines.  Your algorithm sounds nice, but not interesting enough to wade through code like that written by someone else.

Comment: @PeterCordes The purpose of this code wasn't to show how to implement a suffix array (anyone can learn that somewhere else), but rather on how to use a suffix array to solve this problem in special. I didn't even write the suffix array part, it is an adaptation from Halim brothers' [suffix array algorithm in their book](http://cpbook.net/).

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "abababa";
        String prefix;
        int product;
        int maxProduct = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i++) {
            prefix = input.substring(0, i);
            String substr;
            int occurs = 0;
            for (int j = prefix.length(); j <= input.length(); j++) {
                substr = input.substring(0, j);
                if (substr.endsWith(prefix))
                    occurs++;
            }
            product = occurs*prefix.length();
            System.out.println("product of " + prefix + " = " +
                prefix.length() + " * " + occurs +" = " + product);
            maxProduct = (product > maxProduct)?product:maxProduct;
        }
        System.out.println("maxProduct = " + maxProduct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations to your answer?

Comment: That seems to be quadratic because of the two loops no?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this challenge for more than 4 days , reading a lot of documentation, I found a solution with O(N) .

I got 81%, the idea is simple using a window slide.

def solution(s: String): Int = {

```
var max = s.length  // length of the string 
var i, j = 1  // start with i=j=1 ( is the beginning of the slide and j the end of the slide )
val len = s.length // the length of the string 
val count = Array.ofDim[Int](len)  // to store intermediate results 

while (i < len - 1 || j < len) {
  if (i < len && s(0) != s(i)) {
    while (i < len && s(0) != s(i)) {  // if the begin of the slide is different from 
                                      // the first letter of the string skip it 
      i = i + 1
    }
  }
  j = i + 1
  var k = 1


  while (j < len && s(j).equals(s(k))) { // check for equality and update the array count 
    if (count(k) == 0) {
      count(k) = 1
    }
    count(k) = count(k) + 1
    max = math.max((k + 1) * count(k), max)
    k = k + 1
    j = j + 1
  }

  i = i + 1

}

max // return the max
```

}